# Returned promise not expected in cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I deployed the following cloud function:

```
exports.onUserNameUpdated = functions.database.ref('users/{uid}/userName').onUpdate(event => {
    if (event.data.previous.val() === event.data.val()) {
        return;
    }
    const uid = event.data.ref.key();
    const p1 = root.child(`/userlist/${uid}`).set(event.data.val());
    root.child(`following/${key}/list`).once('value').then(snapshot => {
        var followingPromises = [];
        snapshot.forEach(child => {
            const uid2 = child.val().uid;
            const promise = rootRef.child(`followers/${uid2}/list/${key}/userName`).set(event.data.val());
            followingPromises.push(promise);
        });
        return Promises.all(followingPromises);
    }).catch(reason => {
        console.log(reason);
    });
    root.child(`followers/${key}/list`).once('value').then(snapshot => {
        var followerPromises = [];
        snapshot.forEach(child => {
            const uid2 = child.val().uid;
            const promise = root.child(`following/${uid2}/list/${key}/userName`).set(event.data.val());
            followerPromises.push(promise);
        });
        return Promises.all(followerPromises);
    }).catch(reason => {
        console.log(reason);
    });
    return p1;
});
```

When deployed, i received the following warning in terminal:

```
 warning  Arrow function expected no return value  consistent-return
```

It was for the last line of the function, return p1;. Why wasn't the returned promise expected?

Comment: I don't know what that error message means, but I'll say that you have several promises here "dangling" without being factored into the final returned promise that should be resolved when all the work is complete.  Each call to set() and once() and their promise chain, needs to be fully resolved before terminating the function.

Comment: I just set the promise chains to (separate) constants, then returned Promise.all([p1,....]), thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'll say that you have several promises here "dangling" without being factored into the final returned promise that should be resolved when all the work is complete. Each call to set() and once() and their promise chain, needs to be fully resolved before terminating the function.